# Problems sorting data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is, to order these results in such a way that the order is as it is marked gray.

That is to say to obtain every first difference of the column `EjeY`.

[image]

Comment: How is the EjeY field ordered? There doesn't appear to me to be a sorting pattern. How can your results be replicated?

Comment: I believe that this is an island and gap problem. If I  understand what you mean, you want a query that will indicate when a specific change occurs for a specific field and taking only those distinct changes you want to further sort.

Comment: Do you want to sort by `Valor` but *group wise*?

Comment: THE ORDER OF THE FIELD EJEY IS


 1. ALTA/DEFICIENTE
 2.  BAJA/OPTIMA
 3. DEFICIENTE/DEFICIENTE
 4. MEDIA/ALTA
 5.  OPTIMA/DEFICIENTE

Comment: You keep repeating the same comment, but I don't think anyone is clear on what you mean. Do you want a SELECT statement that ONLY picks out those rows in gray? That's a very different thing than you're asking here... this isn't a sorting problem but a selecting problem. You want to group by the first segment of the Ejey column, and take only the first full row based on that.  Is that correct?

Comment: The screenshot is meaningless. Add the query that produced it to your post.

Comment: Should be like this :   i.stack.imgur.com/o6mBd.png

Comment: @DiegoLoaiza, Sorry, but the way you repeat yourself and poste the same / similar picture over and over is annoying... Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to re-word your question. No pictures! sample data **and expected output**

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are looking for this:

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, EjeY VARCHAR(100),Valor INT);
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
 ('Alta/Deviciente',14)
,('Baja/Baja',16)
,('Baja/Media',14)
,('Alta/Alta',8)
,('Alta/Baja',12)
,('Baja/Deviciente',18)
,('Baja/Alta',12)
,('Alta/Optima',6)
,('Alta/Media',10)
,('Baja/Optima',10);

SELECT *
FROM @Dummy AS d
ORDER BY LEFT(EjeY,CHARINDEX('/',EjeY)-1),Valor DESC
```

The result

```
ID  EjeY            Valor
1   Alta/Deviciente 14
5   Alta/Baja       12
9   Alta/Media      10
4   Alta/Alta       8
8   Alta/Optima     6
6   Baja/Deviciente 18
2   Baja/Baja       16
3   Baja/Media      14
7   Baja/Alta       12
10  Baja/Optima     10
```

Comment: THE ORDER OF THE FIELD EJEY IS


 1. ALTA/DEFICIENTE
 2.  BAJA/OPTIMA
 3. DEFICIENTE/DEFICIENTE
 4. MEDIA/ALTA
 5.  OPTIMA/DEFICIENTE

Comment: what? (your CAPS LOCK key is STUCK )

Comment: That should be the records [This][1] [1]: i.stack.imgur.com/o6mBd.png

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to record the changes in the left part of your Ejey delimited field then you need to split the field and then order rank the values by ID.

After you have a ranking you can select the records you are interested in taking the first row of the PARTITION.

```
DECLARE @Dummy TABLE(ID INT, EjeY VARCHAR(100),Valor INT);
INSERT INTO @Dummy VALUES
 (1,'Alta/Deviciente',14)
,(2,'Alta/Baja',12)
,(6,'Baja/Optima',10)
,(7,'Baja/Alta',12)
,(11,'Deficiente/Deficiente',20)
,(11,'Deficiente/Baja',18)
,(16,'Media/Alta',10)
,(17,'Media/Optima',8)
```

--This query will draw a rank in your data based on the LEFT() partition of your Ejey field value.

```
SELECT
    *,
    RowNumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SortPart ORDER BY ID DESC)
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ID,
        SortPart=LEFT(EjeY,CHARINDEX('/',EjeY)-1),
        Valor
    FROM 
        @Dummy
)AS X
```

--This query will further order only the records within your ideal set of data

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        *,
        RowNumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY SortPart ORDER BY ID ASC)
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            ID,
            SortPart=LEFT(EjeY,CHARINDEX('/',EjeY)-1),
            Valor
        FROM 
            @Dummy
    )AS X
)AS Y
WHERE
    RowNumber=1
```

--Results A

```
ID  SortPart    Valor   RowNumber
2   Alta            12  1
1   Alta            14  2
7   Baja            12  1
6   Baja            10  2
11  Deficiente      20  1
11  Deficiente      18  2
17  Media           8   1
16  Media           10  2
```

--Results B

```
ID  SortPart    Valor   RowNumber
1   Alta            14  1
6   Baja            10  1
11  Deficiente      20  1
```

Comment: THE ORDER OF THE FIELD EJEY IS 
   1. ALTA/DEFICIENTE 
   2. BAJA/OPTIMA 
   3. DEFICIENTE/DEFICIENTE 
   4. MEDIA/ALTA 
   5. OPTIMA/DEFICIENTE

My table has 625 records...